# How to track encrypted email links using Google Tag Manager (GTM)

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I'm in the process of setting up Google Tag Manager on one of my sites and want to track email link clicks.

This would normally be straightforward but the challenge is that to reduce SPAM the email links on this site are encrypted using javascript so they look like this:

```
<a href="javascript:void(location.href='mailto:'+String.fromCharCode(102,117,110,100,114,97,105,115,105,110,103,64,98,114,101,110,100,111,110,99,97,114,101,46,111,114,103,46,117,107))">click here</a>
```

Does anyone know how I would go about creating a tag to track clicks of these links and send the data to Analytics?

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: Are you able to add a specific ID or class to these links? If so, then you could create a trigger that would fire based on those IDs or classes.

Comment: I don't think we can unfortunately, good suggestion though

Answer (score 0):

In Google Tag Manager, you can set up a trigger that will identify this, and fire an event tag of your construction. Try the following trigger setup:

[image: Trigger Setup Example]

Comment: Since presumable not all emails are the same I'd rather use "Click url contains mailto" or a regular expression.

Comment: @EikePierstorff Yes; I was trying to keep this one simple, but would usually create a much more general trigger, and an accompanying variable that would allow me to output relevant data from the link itself.

Comment: You're right @EikePierstorff, emails vary which means that the javascript code also varies. I've now realised that even if we can get GTM to track these email links, the data that it sends through to GA will not be much use as that will also be encrypted. The emails are encrypted to try to reduce SPAM. Back to the drawing board I think.

Comment: @TomPerkins I was just trying to give the most easily-followed solution. If you have the capability, instead you could give all of these links a custom class for Google Tag Manager to look out for.

Comment: @TomPerkins Encryption shouldn't be a problem; you've got Google Tag Manager here in between the site and Google Analytics. In the Tag Manager console, you can use custom variables to undo the encryption. You should be careful not to send email addresses to Google Analytics though!